Does declaration "using type = type;" change the meaning of type?
Given the following example, gcc prints a warning. clang accepts it just fine. Who's right?
From my point of view, type was an alias for int before using-declaration, and it still is an alias for int in complete class context. So I would expect there's no change in meaning.
using  type = int;

struct Test
{
    using type = type;  // gcc: declaration of 'using Test::type = using type = int' changes meaning of 'type'
};

void foo(Test::type);

Or is it one of "no diagnostic required" situations?

A compiler warning is just that:  a warning that the compiler has deigned fit to alert you (the programmer) about, because their is something in the code that the compiler has flagged as suspicious.  It's a built-in linter as part of the compiler.  If you don't want a compiler warning, there is probably one-or-more mechanisms to disable the warning.

using type = ::type; should prevent the warning, if you don't want to disable the warning.

@Eljay, thank you for the nice workaround, but my primary interest is not to suppress the warning, but to understand whether that warning is founded or is it a false alarm. That is, if the code above is suspicious or ill-formed, I'd like to know what's wrong with it.

IMHO, using X = X; is redundant, but not illegal.  A super nice compiler should issue a warning about "do you really want to do this?".  There may be higher priority issues that need work other than this..

@IgorG ::type is not a workaround, it is being explicit (that you mean the type in the global namespace and not the type in  Test. I would consider this good practice because it alerts the reader of your code that this is exactly what you mean. Unless you ofcourse really try to define a type as itself (which would not make sense)

@PepijnKramer, and yet, is that code well-formed, as it stands? This here is just a minimal stripped example, in real code I would like that declaration to be valid in any unknown namespace, not only in the global namespace.

@Eljay -- a compiler warning can be a form of mandatory diagnostic for non-conforming code under the C++ standard. The standard requires that compilers "issue a diagnostic", not that they refuse to compile the code. Compiler-specific language extensions take advantage of this rule by issuing a warning and then compiling the code with their extension. I'm not saying that's what's happening here, just commenting on the meaning of a "warning" in standardese.

For me good code is not only about "correctness/well defined" but also about expressing intent.

@PepijnKramer, the intent is being able to refer to that type as Test::type. Test is a autogenerated traits class that is used as template parameter for other classes, and they expect to find Test::type. Ok, I see... XY problem...

Apparently, this is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. There is an issue in LLVM to support this warning (or if possible make it an error), but nobody picked it up yet: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/77970. I don't quite understand what is the issue per standard, maybe somebody else can pick it up and write an answer.

@Yksisarvinen Hm... In that issue the change in meaning is obvious: B was a struct and then became a member function. What change in meaning happens here, then?

gcc seems to explain it in warning documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wchanges-meaning. Yes, they are the same type, so it's only a warning (though they say it's still ill-formed per standard). If you changed the meaning to different type, it would be an error (as in the example copied from LLVM issue: https://godbolt.org/z/c6Wv9hbMG). Whether this is really ill-formed according to letter of standard or gcc is overreacting - I can't tell.

Out of curiosity, in what sort of situation would this realistically even happen? Conditionally (e.g. ifdef) redefining types? Some sort of SFINAE logic?

@Xellos it was an attempt to create a class that would act as a medium, for capturing types visible in the current scope (whatever that scope might be) and then passing those captured types as parameter for some other algorithm.
